# Login without redirection due to error

Tags: php, forms

```
<?php

session_start();
if(isset($_POST['id1'])||isset($_POST['mob1']))
{
    $id = htmlentities($_POST['id1']);
    $mobile =htmlentities($_POST['mobile1']);
    $connect =new mysqli("localhost","root","password","test");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `User` WHERE `id`='$id' AND `mobile`='$mobile'";
    $sql1 ="SELECT * FROM `User` WHERE `id`='$id'";
    if($connect->connect_error)
    {
        die("connection failed : ".$connect->connect_error);
    }
    if($res=mysqli_query($connect,$sql))
    {
        $count=mysqli_num_rows($res);

        if($count>0){
            $link="/new.html";
            $_SESSION['user']=$id;

            header("Location: ".$link);
            exit();
        }
        $count1 = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connect,$sql1));
        if($count1==1)
        {
             $_SESSION['user']='passworderror';
        }
        else{
             $_SESSION['user']='usernameerror';
        }
    }
}


?>
```

I am submitting a login form from login.php and checking for password ,username form errors in checklogin.php.And send response through $_SESSION[''] appropriately but i tends to get redirected to checklogin.php page automatically when i submit the form!

Comment: Because that's probably what you wrote it to do. If you don't want the form to submit and redirect the prevent the default behaviour and use AJAX or if you are wanting to go to the same page do `action=""`. Also, please describe what behaviour you want.

Comment: I second that ^^ @SpencerWieczorek

Comment: Not to mention that code is atrocious. I almost wanna rewrite the entire thing.

Comment: can u tell me hw would you rewrite it ??@JasonBassett